# Change frame of present viewController of UIModalPresentationFormSheet model style

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uimodalpresentationstyle

how to change frame of presented viewController of model style "UIModalPresentationFormSheet"

expected frame [image]

current frame [image]

i have tried setting view bounds OverlayViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(20,20,600,400)

have set frame and center of presenting view

```
OverlayViewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask =
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        OverlayViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,600,400);
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(screenBounds), CGRectGetMidY(screenBounds));
```

have also tried `setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPageSheet` with frame was not able to set origin for page sheet

so please suggest how this have to be done

Comment: So you'r problem has been solved?

Comment: yes by setting self.navigationcontroller.superview.frame in viewDidLoad of presenting view

Comment: Oh thats really great. post as answer so for others it would be helpful also